# In this situation, which model is better?

Tags: keras

There are two neural network models.

The first model doesn't have any regularization and shows overfitting from epoch 10. So this model stops training at epoch 9. The least validation loss happens at epoch 9.

The second model has a regularization(Dropout) and doesn't show overfitting. So this model keeps training much longer than the first model. But the least validation loss value isn't higher than first model's least validation loss value. Even though this model can train much more, this model doesn't seem to reach the value of the first model's least validation loss.

Those models train the same dataset and structure is almost same except whether using regularization or not.

In this situation, which one is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use the first one if you can say with any certainty that it is over fitted. The loss value is calculated based on the training set not the test set, so the value might be high, but that doesn't mean the model will perform well with the test data.
If the second model continues to get different loss values at later epohcs, but loss isn't decreasing, you could try tinkering with the parameters or model structure to find the right balance. But I'd be more likely to trust a model that is not overfitted in most scenarios.

Comment: Also look into using scipy train_test_split in order to generate test data. This can be passed into model.fit as "validation", which can give you new metrics to judge the performance of your model

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I want to get confirmation so I will ask this to you one more time.

Based on your answer, even though I trained the first model before epoch 10(before getting overfitting),  it is not good idea to use first model. Right?

Comment: Every machine learning problem is different, so it is hard to say for sure that you should/shouldn't use a certain model. Another great way to decrease the likelihood of overfitting is to simply use more training data! I would probably try that with the first model before giving up on it.